# How to set the class of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I think about saving objects using `JSON.stringify` and later load them again. The "stringification" works well of course, however I am not sure how I would set the prototype/class of an object.

Comment: FYI JSON.stringify is not on all browsers versions.....

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @RoyiNamir But it is available as a separate download from http://json.org.

Comment: @MichaelTodd Did you see the 3 first letters in my comment :-) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Hm... so what? :)

Comment: @VisioN Comment to let the OP **to know** there is a trap.

Comment: @RoyiNamir While Michael's comment just stated the solution for that. Nothing special.

Comment: @VisioN there is a difference between _But it is available as a separate..._ VS  _And it is available as a separate.._ .  The [but] can make other people to think the FYI comment is incorrect. while it is , AND there is a solution which can be found at...

Comment: Please be sure to check the most helpful answer  , so that other people will continue helping you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.toJSON` and reviver callback to achieve this.

Here is the scheme:

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "name";
    this.age = "age";
}

Person.prototype.toJSON = function() {
            //Define this for other classes as well
    return {__class__: "Person", name: this.name, age: this.age};
};

function reviver( key, value ) {
        if( typeof value == "object" && value.__class__ ) {
            var ret = new window[value.__class__];
            for( var k in value ) {
                if( k === "__class__" ) continue;
                ret[k] = value[k];
            }
            return ret;
        }
        return value;
}

var a = new Person(),
    b = new Person();

var json = JSON.stringify( [a,b] );

var decoded = JSON.parse( json, reviver);

console.log( decoded ); //[Person, Person] I.E. array of Person instances instead of plain objects
```

in this simplified scheme, the class must be global.

Comment: **brilliant answer**. ( p.s. In real life , should I embed what type of Object the json string was?)

Comment: Testing your code ,  IMHO you missed `()` after `new window[value.__class__];`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir `()` is not necessary after `new`

Comment: nevermind that why the browser warned me about.... why did you used `new window [...]` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir `new window[value.__class__]` == `new window["Person"] == `new Person`

Comment: Other option was to use eval(value.__class__)... no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir not really... that is a waste of eval, the bracket syntax works. The eval is evil actually comes from people using eval over bracket syntax

Comment: So creating objects with Eval can be totaly replaced by `new window[x]` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir no, property access with dynamic strings can... come on I'm sure you know about `obj.prop` vs `obj["prop"]`?

Comment: @RoyiNamir in the second, we can also use a variable.. like `var a = "prop"` and then `obj[a]`

Comment: I meant :`var o={}; o["22"]=123; //its ok` ...while this : `o.33=333;` will fail

Comment: you made me ask this question  :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294714/json-parse-reviver-function-has-n1-keys

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22637/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-esailija)