# JSON.parse reviver function has n+1 keys?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, reviver-function

*I wanted to [test the code overload which can provide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#highlighter_131907) a reviver function when parsing a JSON string.*

So this code:

```
JSON.parse('{"p": 5}', function(k, v) { if (k === "") return v; return v * 2; }).p;
```

yields `10` (ok).

But then I asked myself, 'what is this `if (k === "")` thing?' Lets remove it!:

```
JSON.parse('{"p": 5}', function(k, v) { return v*2;}).p; //undefined !!
```

Maybe because 5 is an integer? Let's try with `parseInt`:

```
JSON.parse('{"p": 5}', function(k, v) { return parseInt(v)*2;}).p; //undefined !!
```

Very weird...

So then I wanted to see which keys (although there is only one here) are causing the trouble:

```
JSON.parse('{"p": 5}', function(k, v) { alert(v)}).p;
```

There were 2 alerts:

- `5`
- `[object Object]`

IMHO `k` and `v` are for `key` and `value`, and indeed there is only one key here.

**What** is this other alert? And **why** do I have to check `if (k === "")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the link you provided...

> The reviver is ultimately called with the empty string and the topmost value to permit transformation of the topmost value.

`v` is the object itself in the case of `k === ""`

Comment: I guess I should do an eye check.

Comment: v is the inner object or the outer whole object ?

Comment: Which inner object? There's an object with a key `p`. Open the console (ctrl+i in Chrome, ctrl+shift+k in Firefox) and paste `JSON.parse('{"p": 5}', function(k, v) { console.log(v); return v; });`

Comment: It's the whole thing `{"p": {"a":2}}`. What else should it be?

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"p": {"a":2}}', function(k, v) { if (k === "") alert(v.p.a); return v * 2; });` alerts undefined. isn't it suppose to return 2?

Comment: In case of `k === ""` there's no return statement = undefined. Thus you make the whole thing undefined.

Comment: IMHO the return is for the outer assignment. it should alert 2

Comment: Forget what I wrote above: the `v * 2` returns `NaN` because `v` contains `{a: 4}`. And the case `k === ""` is the very last, thus `v.p.a` is in fact `NaN.a` which is undefined.

Comment: wrote above where ? you wrote many lines...can you edit your answer so it will be clearer also to others :-) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22638/discussion-between-prinzhorn-and-royi-namir)